# How to add values from array to textbox in a while loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop, cart

I have products on a loop in a shopping cart, but the values of qty is not appearing it have this error on every textbox.  
**Notice**:  Array to string conversion in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\cart.php** on line **172**
Array

```
<?php 
    $total = 0;

    global $con; 

    $ip = getIp(); 

    $sel_price = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip'";

    $run_price = mysqli_query($con, $sel_price); 

    while($p_price=mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)){

        $pro_id = $p_price['p_id']; 

        $pro_price = "select * from products where product_id='$pro_id'";

        $run_pro_price = mysqli_query($con,$pro_price); 

        while ($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro_price)){

        $product_price = array($pp_price['product_price']);

        $product_title = $pp_price['product_title'];

        $product_image = $pp_price['product_image']; 

        $single_price = $pp_price['product_price'];
        $single_price = number_format($single_price);
        $values = array_sum($product_price); 
        $total += $values;  


        $pro_qty = "select * from cart where p_id='$pro_id'";

        $run_pro_qty = mysqli_query($con,$pro_qty); 

        while ($pp_qty = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro_qty)){

        $product_qty = array($pp_qty['qty']);

                ?>

                <tr align="center">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $pro_id;?>"/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product_title; ?><br>
                    <img src="admin_area/product_images/<?php echo $product_image;?>" width="60" height="60"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="4" name="qty" value="<?php echo $product_qty;?>"/></td>
                    <td><?php echo "Php " . $single_price; ?></td>
                </tr>
    <?php } }?>
```

Comment: it makes no sense to echo an array. You can echo an array after imploding something like a comma.

Comment: why you are not simply echoing `$pp_qty['qty']` instead of putting it into an array and trying to echo that array?

Comment: it's ok thanks, btw how can i get a button and if the textbox change it will change all the qty in database.

Comment: are you shure that you want to display all products with the given productid from your cart table in your second cart-query? it would show all products bought by all users from cart. it makes less sense.

Comment: i would have an ip address recorded for that

Comment: but the ip-adress is not included in your second cart-query and the ip adress is not unique for one user. If i am connected via mobile phone my provider gives the same ip to all customers. Another case is that 2 persons from the same network try to add something to cart. You should not use the ip-adress for that.

Comment: It looks like you're using some custom ecommerce solution. My question is why? There are so many opensource solutions, not to mention you can get into a world of trouble with PCI compliance if you don't do it right.